# How to pass array parameter to middleware in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-middleware

i don't know the syntax of php 7 i'm actually new to it
i'm trying to pass roles like ['admin','user','cmc'] to route middleware like shown below how do i do it properly

this is my route

```
  Route::get('/dashboard','HomeController@dashboard')->name('dashboard')->middleware("roles:['admin','user']");
```

//how do i pass array of roles in it

//role middleware

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use App\Role;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;


class Roles
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next,$role)
    {
        Log::info($role);
        if($request->user()==null){
            return response('unauthorised Access detected',401);
        }
        //check for any role passed from array 
        if($request->user()->hasAnyRole($role)){
            return $next($request);
        }        
        return response('unauthorised Access detected',401);
    }
}
```

//usermodel

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
    public function role(){
        return $this->hasMany(Role::class);
    }
    public function hasANyRole($roles){
        if(is_array($roles)){
            foreach($roles as $role){
                if($this->hasRole($role)){
                    return true;
                }
            }return false;
        }else{
            if($this->hasRole($roles)){
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
    public function hasRole($role){
        if($this->role()->where('role',$role)->first()){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public function getRole(){
    return $this->role()->select('role')->get();
    }

}
```

how do i pass role like ['admin','user','cmc'] some thing like this into the middleware of role

the problem is i can only get the first value in the array and the rest is not there
can some one get me out of this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a similar situation where I wanted to check if a user is an owner or admin before visiting a route; so I didn't need duplicate routes, and needed to pass an array instead of set single parameters.

I went down the route of sending a single paramter but using an | as a delimiter to explode on the middlewhere class.

In the route I had this for the route group
`Route::group(['middleware' => ['checkRole:admin|owner']], function () {`

and then in the middlewhere I used explode

```
$roles = explode('|', $permitted_roles);
```

Simple looped through the roles array to check if the user had one of the roles :) Hope this helps. Simple and easy for what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can send your parameters separated with comma (which means you're sending more than one parameters):

```
Route::middleware('my_middleware:param1,param2');
```

And then get them in the `handle` function of the middleware as *variable function arguments*:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$param_array): Response
{
    //use $param_array as an array consisting of parameters sent
    //example: if(in_array($request->param, $param_array)) {do some logic}
}
```

[Credits](https://ahesanalisuthar.wordpress.com/2015/06/04/laravel-5-1-pass-middleware-parameters-as-array/)